# How To Use Msg /Server: * /time " " In LAN Networks With IP?

Tags: cmd, lan, msg

I use this command in my laptop in cmd console:

```
msg /Server:mohammad * /Time:5 "The MSG"
```

But how can I use it with an IP Address?

Answer (score 5):

- Open the Registry Editor.
- In the left pane, locate and then click the following registry subkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server`
- In the right pane, ensure value of `AllowRemoteRPC` key is `1`.

  - If not, please change it to `1`.
- Quit Registry Editor and Reboot the computer.
- Run MSG command in a elevated CMD window.

Comment: Will this work from Win7 to Win10 on the same network/router? Or using the public IP? I've tried several combinations. I did this step way back and it's still a '1'. changed my Win10Pro SP4 pc too recently. Tried creating firewalls exceptions for port 445. Nothing. Not working still. What is the exact command also? >msg mikepc /server:pcname hi, or >msg 192.168.1.5 /server:pcname hi, or msg mikepc /server:192.168.1.5 hi? I understand msg * /SERVER, the asterisk is send to everyone right?

Answer (score 3):

command **msg * /SERVER:192.168.1.107** worked for me

Comment: Asterisk is for all users right? How would you send to user mikeylikesit? >msg mikeylikesit /SERVER:192.168.1.200? I'm sending from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.200 and it's not working out. I've enabled Terminal Server via regedit by entering 1 already (years ago). I've even tried public IP. Nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>msg /server:192.168.1.200 ejbytes /w hi
Error 5 getting session names

Comment: enable network sharing

Answer (score -1):

MSG /SERVER:192.168.1.1 /TIME:05 * HELLO WORLD

/TIME:05  -  SECONDS TO DISPLAY THE MENSSAGE
 *     -   MACHINE USER, IF YOU DON'T KNOW USE *
 192.168.1.1 - DESTINATION USER NAME OR IP

USER FROM IP 192.168.1.1 RECEIVES THE TEXT: HELLO WORLD  ----> SEE PRINT SCREEN

[image: SEE PRINT SCREEN]

Answer (score -4):

You can do it with:

1. goto cmd prompt
2. type syntax as follows

   `net send ipaddress of reciever "message to be send"`

   ex: `net send 192.168.0.1 "hello"`

   OR

   `MSG * /SERVER:192.168.1.1 Hello`

   If you want to send this on a Domain you must be an administrator

   (net send is not available in Windows 7*)

Comment: No No i don`t want to use Net Send, In My LAN It`s Not Enabled And **I Don`t Want To Enable it**.
**MSG** Command Is Good **But** How to use IP Address Instead Of Server:ComputerName ?
If You Know My Answer Please Test before Posting it.


Thanks

Comment: Command:
    MSG * /SERVER:computer.domain.com Hello
  I found that if I used the IP it would get sent.  I tried adding a period to the end of .com and it sent.  
Command:
    `MSG * /SERVER:192.168.1.1 Hello`
    or
    `MSG * /SERVER:computer.domain.com. Hello`
Thanks and let me know if you facing trouble.

Comment: Thanks G Patel    . but this command MSG * /SERVER:192.168.1.1 Hello. does n`t work. i tested it before. Is there any solution?

Comment: Hi @ILI , You may be restricted on your LAN network, You may require few registry settings , Please have a look on this link: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/how-send-messages-through-ip-104959.S.214724819 
You may find New idea for that.

Comment: Hi Mr.G Patel   .I Know that I must Enable some settings For Use NET SEND.But In our Network it`s impossible, The MSG Command Is better. it work with Computer Name But I can`t work with its IP parameters.I just want to send some message or Text to another computer in LAN Network.!!

Comment: Hi@ILI , Why don't you try with other option same like command prompt. `MESSENGER`.

You can Find more about it: http://www.wikihow.com/Chat-With-Command-Prompt

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply.The Admin Of LAN Network Closed any permission to access the service to Enable it.But now I go my  Services In My PC to enable messenger But there isn`t any messenger!! what is problem? and how to Enable it With CMD?

Comment: @ILI, This will not work on Windows 7, Vista, ME, 95, 98, I was assume you have same OS.
 Again it's depend on your operating system,
 Why don't you try third party messager: http://messenger.softros.com/

Comment: Because of I`m A computer Engineer and studying Computer Science, I want to know The Commands Or Source NOT Any App Programs. OK! No Problem Thanks, If you know any Solution in future please Put Here. Bye